How to deserialize into wrapper object (jms serializer)?
I use jms serializer (https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) outside symfony framework. I had structure of response like that:
[
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
]

When I use
$serializer->deserialize($json, 'ArrayCollection<NAMESPACE/ITEM>', 'json');

it works great and I get ArrayCollection of obects, but I want to wrap it to object of ItemsWrapper which simulates json structure like:
{
    "items": 
        [
            { "id": 1 },
            { "id": 2 }
        ]
}

I try to do that by add wrapper class with property:
   /**
   * @Type("ArrayCollection<NAMESPACE/ITEM>")
   */
    private $items;

and deseralize like that:
$serializer->deserialize($json, NAMESPACE/ItemsWrapper::class, 'json');

But It doesn't work I get object ItemsWrapper with null inside items property.
Can I achieve my goal without add listeners/subsribers or deserialize to existing object (https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/object_constructor)??
